# Close as duplicate circle detection bug

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Trying to cast a close vote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7345122/73226) as being duplicate of the question "[Maximum size for a SQL Server Query? ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1869753/73226)" throws up an error that "This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle"

How can that be the case? The question was only asked 13 minutes ago? Surely there can't be another question closed as duplicate of that which would complete the circle?

Comment: This looks thorny to unpick, but I will disable the check ASAP so that it doesn't cause issues.

Comment: (this is currently disabled; you should be able to vote now)

Comment: Yep. That works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of this; it relates to some of our older posts (i.e. 2009) where some particulars of dup-voting worked differently. A fix has been applied, and will be deployed in due course. *Until* it is deployed, this check will be left disabled.

Comment: please, check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069078/trying-to-use-a-nested-for-loops-w-2-variables-keeping-1-the-same-while-runnin) with circle duplicate pointed to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069755/simplified-create-a-nested-for-loop-for-the-data-and-plug-the-4-values-i-get), the bug seems to persist...

Comment: I found through [SO the review tool](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2660747)